# Matrix of different shaped matrices Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a linear system of equation via numpy.linal.solve with python.
The equation would look like this : **Ax=b**.

In my case A should be a matrix of different matrices **[[W,U.T],[U,0]]**,
where W is a 150x150 numpy array, U.T is a 150x11 numpy array and U therefore a 11x150 numpy array. 
The result b should be a vector looking like this : **[0,y]**,
where y is a 1x11 vector.

My porblem is that I don't know how to concatenate the matrices of matrix A.
I already tried to use concatenate or the stack operator of the numpy class. But that results in an 161x161 matrix A and I need a 2x2 matrix.
Therefore I gues I have to deal with every matrix as one entry but I don't know how to do that, cause of the different shapes.

I hope someone can help me. I'm really stuck here.

Comment: how do you want to get a 2x2 matrix starting off from 161x161 elements?

Comment: A (2,2) array would be object dtype, containing arrays.  `np.linalg.solve` cannot be used for that.  It requires a numeric array, such as the (161,161) shaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your matrix to be twodimensional and make sure to maintain the correct mathematical expression.

If I'm not mistaking, what you want is to express the following equations:

```
W_1,1 x_1 + W_1,2 x_2 + ... + W_1,150 x_150 + U_1,1 x_151 + ... + U_11,1 x_161 = 0
...
W_150,1 x_1 + W_150,2 x_2 + ... + W_150,150 x_150 + U_1,150 x_151 + ... + U_11,150 x_161 = 0
U_1,1 x_1 + ... + U_1,150 x_150 = y_1
...
U_11,1 x_1 + ... + U_11,150 x_150 = y_11
```

Therefore, you will need a Matrix `A` of shape `(161, 161)` where the top left corner is filled with `(150x150)` elements of `W`, the top right corner is filled with `(150x11)` elements of `U.T`, the bottom left corner is filled with (11x150) elements of `U` and the bottom right corner is filled with `(11x11)` zeros.
Your Array `b` will be of shape `(161,)` containing 151 zeros and 11 elements of `y`.

I.e.:

```
A[:150,:150] = W
A[:150,150:] = U.T
A[150:,:150] = U
A[150:,150:] = 0

b[:150] = 0
b[150:] = y
```

Make sure all your quantities are numpy arrays.
The result `x` will have shape (161,) as well.

I don't think that np.linalg.solve supports nested dimensions. But it should not be nesessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I constructed a vector b, that was wrong. It's working now.